# Continually compressing a stderr stream

Tags: shell, compression, tar

Is there some way to continually compress the output of a program (in almost realtime)?

For example I have this program that produces (a lot of) output to stderr. I want to do something like `./my-program 2> tar -<someoptions> stderroutput.tar.gz`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to compress the contents of the standard error stream and save it to a file.  If so, try this:
`./my-program 2>&1 | gzip > stderroutput.gz`

Answer (score 4):

`tar` does not compress data; it is designed only to archive multiple **files** into one. To compress streams, you would need to use `gzip`, `xz`, `bzip2` or similar. (While `gzip` has the worst compression rate, it is also one of the fastest, so it might be the best choice here.)

For example:

```
myapp 2> >(gzip > stderr.gz)
```

or

```
(myapp 2>&1 1>&3 | gzip > stderr.gz) 3>&1
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that tar doesn't compress data (only files). Thanks.

Comment: @trex279: Strictly speaking, tar doesn't compress *at all*. It only packs files into archives, and automatically calls `gzip`/etc to perform compression.